# How to set product custom options value in Order?

Tags: product, custom-options

I am getting here product custom option value.
Here is my code.

```
$orderId = 100017234;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item)
{
  $productOptions = $item->getProductOptions();
  foreach ($productOptions['options'] as $key => $value)
  {
    echo $value['value']; // HOW CAN I SET THIS VALUE ??
  }
}
```

Can anyone help to set this value.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code :

```
orderId = 100017234;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $productOptions = $item->getProductOptions();
    foreach ($productOptions['options'] as $key => $value)
    {
        $productOptions['your_custom_option'] = $yourCustomValue;
        $item->setProductOptions($productOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you rejected this? without version how you can specify? https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/95920

Comment: @manashvi-birls: This is not saving the changes done in order data. Any idea?

Comment: @manashvi-birls: This works in my case when I add save() i.e.,
$item->setProductOptions($productOptions)->save();